# Boton editar no me actualiza los datos de formulario modal

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Tengo un problema que cuando le doy click al boton editar, me abre el modal con los datos actuales, pero cuando decido cambiarle la información y guardarlo, me muestra el mensaje que el registro fue cambiado pero en realidad no modificó nada.

Este es el código de la ventana modal editar para poder realizar la modificación de los datos de la base de datos:

```
 <?php 

    if(isset($_GET['idProducto']))
    {
        $idProducto = $_GET['idProducto'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM productos WHERE idProducto='$idProducto' ";
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
            $idProducto = $row['idProducto'];
            $producto = $row['producto'];
            $categoría = $row['categoría'];
            $precio = $row['precio'];
        }
    }
    ?>
    <!-- VENTANA MODAL EDITAR -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="editProd<?php echo $row['idProducto']; ?>" tabindex="-1" 
    aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">


                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="modalTittle">Editar producto</h1>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria- 
    label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form method="POST" class="agg-product mb-1" action="botonesProd.php" >
                                <?php include('errors.php'); ?>
                                <input type="hidden" name="idProducto" value="<?= 
    $productos['idProducto']; ?>">

                                <div class="mb-3">
                                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form- 
    label">Producto</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="producto" 
    placeholder="Ingresar producto" value="<?php echo $row['producto'];?>">
                                </div>

                                <div class="mb-3">
                                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form- 
    label">Categoría</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="categoría" 
    placeholder="Ingresar categoría" value="<?php echo $row['categoría'];?>">
                                </div>

                                <div class="mb-3">
                                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form- 
    label">Precio</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="precio" 
    placeholder="Ingresar precio" value="<?php echo $row['precio'];?>">
                                </div>

                                <!-- Botones de modal -->
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs- 
    dismiss="modal" name="btn-cerrar">Cerrar</button>
                                    <input type="submit" name="actualizarProd" class="btn 
    btn-primary" value="Actualizar">
                                </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Y este es mi código donde tengo el update para poder actualizar los datos en la base de datos:

```
 <?php
    include('server.php');    
    
        //MODIFICACION *********************************************
        if (isset($_POST['actualizarProd'])) {

        $idProducto = $_POST['idProducto'];
        $producto =  $_POST['producto'];
        $categoría = $_POST['categoría'];
        $precio =  $_POST['precio'];

        $query = "UPDATE productos SET producto='$producto', categoría='$categoría', 
        precio='$precio' WHERE idProducto='$idProducto' ";

        $query_run = mysqli_query($db, $query);
        if($query_run)
        {
            $_SESSION['message'] = "Registro cambiado!";
            header("Location: productos.php");
            exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            $_SESSION['message'] = "Error al modificar registro.";
            header("Location: productos.php");
            exit(0);
        }
    }


    ?>
```

Estas son algunas imagenes del mensaje que el registro fue cambiado pero en realidad, no cambió nada:

[image: Modal de editar con datos actuales]

[image: Precio cambiado del producto libreta a $5555]

[image: Mensaje que el registro fue modificado pero sin ninguna actualización de los datos]

Comment: Hola. Considera no abusar de las negritas en la redacción de la pregunta, úsalas solamente si quieres resaltar algo en específico. En cuanto al problema que planteas aquí, el hecho de que esto se cumpla `if($query_run)` en una consulta del tipo `UPDATE` o `DELETE` no significa que se hayan actualizado o borrado registros. El valor que debes verificar es [`affected_rows`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.affected-rows.php). Si la actualización no ocurre como esperas puede ser porque el `WHERE` no se cumple o por otros motivos. La única forma de saberlo es depurando el código.

Answer (score 0):

El hecho de que esto se cumpla `if($query_run)` en una consulta del tipo `UPDATE`,`DELETE` o `INSERT` **no significa que se hayan actualizado** (o borrado o insertado registros según el caso). **El valor que debes verificar en esos casos es [`affected_rows`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.affected-rows.php)**. Una llamada a `query()` será `true` cuando la consulta se haya ejecutado exitosamente, es decir, no hubo error de sintaxis, etc, pero eso no implica *per se* una actualización de datos, o un borrado de datos o una inserción de datos. Hay al menos dos casos en los que un `UPDATE` no actualiza ninguna fila:

1. No se cumple la condición `WHERE`
2. Los datos que mandas a actualizar realmente no cambian nada.

   Por ejemplo, `query()` devolverá `true` en una consulta como esta: `` UPDATE `people` SET `name`='Brenda' WHERE `name`='Brenda'; ``. Devuelve `true` porque no hay error de sintaxis, suponiendo que existe una tabla llamada `people` y tiene una columna llamada `name`. **Pero esa consulta no afectará a ninguna fila**, sea porque no existes en la base de datos, sea porque ya te llamas `Brenda`, o sea, no hay nada que actualizar realmente en este caso.

Veo este error de lógica en muchas preguntas aquí, quizá porque aprenden ustedes de tutoriales que han sido escritos sin revisar la documentación (lee sobre `affected_rows` en el enlace de más arriba).

Dicho eso, conviene que apliques más cosas en tu código:

- El mismo es altamente vulnerable a ataques de *inyección SQL*
- No debes pasar a buscar datos en super globales sin verificar si existen, pues te expondrías a situaciones de *`Undefined index`*
- Convendría un control estricto, donde verifiques al más mínimo detalle el estado de cada cosa: conexión, posible consulta errónea, etc.
- Como ya dije más arriba, debes usar las propiedades adecuadas para la verificación, la cual es `affected_rows` para este caso.

Propongo lo siguiente:

```
<?php
    include('server.php');    
    
    //MODIFICACION *********************************************
    if (isset($_POST['actualizarProd'])) {
        $idProducto = $_POST['idProducto'] ?? NULL;
        $producto =  $_POST['producto'] ?? NULL;
        $categoría = $_POST['categoría'] ?? NULL;
        $precio =  $_POST['precio'] ?? NULL;
        if ( isset($idProducto) && isset($producto) && isset($categoría) && isset($precio) ) {
            if ($db) {
                #Consulta preparada para evitar inyección SQL
                $query = "UPDATE productos SET producto=?, categoría=?, 
        precio=? WHERE idProducto=?";
                if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, $query) ) {
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssi", $producto,$categoria,$precio,$idProducto);
                    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                    $numRows= mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt);
                    $msg=sprintf("Filas actualizadas: %d",$numRows);
                } else {
                    $msg="Error preparando la consulta";
                }
            } else {
                $msg="No hay conexión a la base de datos";
            }
        } else {
            $msg="Faltan datos en el POST";
        }
    } else {
            $msg="No se solicitó actualización";
    }

    #Ponemos el valor que tenga $msg
    #según lo ocurrido a lo largo del código
    $_SESSION['message'] = $msg;
    header("Location: productos.php");
    exit(0);

?>
```

#### Enlaces de interés

Te dejo aquí los enlaces de las diferentes funciones que he usado.

- [`affected_rows`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php) es la propiedad adecuada a verificar cuántas filas fueron afectadas en un `UPDATE`, `DELETE` o `INSERT`
- [`mysqli_prepare`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php), para consultas preparadas, a fin de evitar *inyección SQL*. Se usa con `bind_param` y con `execute`. En el enlace hay ejemplos y están los enlaces a cada una de las funciones con las que trabaja.
- Para verificar los datos del POST he usado el operador de [*fusión de null* (`??`)](https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration70.new-features.php). Es una característica nueva de PHP 7. Si estás en una versión anterior de PHP puedes cambiarlo por operadores ternarios.

Comment: Voy a considerar tus consejos, muchas gracias. He intentado cambiar mi código por el que me dejaste para realizar la modificación, pero me tira un error de syntaxis: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "&&" . 
Me parece raro ya que es un operador lógico que se utiliza para php. Parece que hay algo que no estoy logrando que hace que me salte un error de syntaxis.

Comment: @Brenda error mío, puse paréntesis de más en algún `isset`, intenta con el nuevo código ya corregido.

Comment: Buenisimo! El error ya no está, pero sigue sin actualizarme los datos. Me muestra el mensaje pero no me lo actualiza.

Comment: ¿Qué mensaje muestra exactamente @Brenda?

Comment: El mensaje que muestra es: 
Filas actualizadas: 0

Comment: @Brenda si sale eso es por lo ya dicho: no hay nada que actualizar, sea porque el `WHERE` no se cumple, sea porque mandas a actualizar con los mismos datos que ya existen. Considera verificar eso. Puedes hacer un `printf("idProducto: %s producto: %s categoría: %s precio: %s", $idProducto, $producto, $categoría, $precio);` y verificar si ese `$idProducto` existe en la base de datos y si los datos serían distintos. Por cierto veo algo extraño con la variable `$categoria`, en unas partes aparece con `i`  acentuada y en otras no.

Comment: Muy bien, voy a revisar nuevamente el código y verificar cual es el error. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Ya acabo de corregir la variable que estaba sin acentuar. Saludos!

Comment: @Brenda es mejor no usar acentos, ni `ñ` ni caracteres especiales en variables, o nombres de tablas, columnas o en nombres de etiquetas en el HTML. Los acentos pueden romper el código en ciertos entornos donde no tengas control estricto de la codificación.

Comment: Ahh bien, entonces lo voy a cambiar por si eso me esta o puede causar algun problema. Muchas gracias por todos tus consejos, los tengo en cuenta.